# onblur doesn't trigger on iPad when using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ios, ajax, onblur

I've currently just got a datatable through ajax and was wanting to be able to inline edit it. Everything works fine on desktop however when attempting to use the site on iOS it appears the onblur doesn't trigger the update.

Is there any way to be able to make this work for iOS and Desktop users?

```
$(document).on('blur', '.update', function(){
var id = $(this).data("id");
var email = $(this).data("email");
var value = $(this).text();
update_data(id, email, value);
}
```

Comment: It's iOS bug, you can check google for more information

Comment: Hi. can you kindly add to your question related HTML slice of code?

Comment: Not really any html to it. I google but couldn't find anything on how to make it work ):